# iptables prerouting don't work

Tags: linux, networking, debian, iptables

I used this command block for routing 80 to 8080, but it's not working now

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlp8s0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

and `iptables -L -vt nat` output is;

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 3 packets, 236 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 REDIRECT   tcp  --  wlp8s0 any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http redir ports 8080

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 2 packets, 184 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 2 packets, 128 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 2 packets, 128 bytes)
```

and finally, `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` output => 1

uname output;

```
Linux 4.9.0-3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.30-2+deb9u3 (2017-08-06) GNU/Linux
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Please describe the behavior you were getting, the behavior you are getting now,  and what changed between then and now.

Comment: I don't change anything on commands, only my ip address change

Comment: All client know my new ip adress so ı thinking issue on iptables.normally prerouting pkts and bytes section(iptables -L -vt nat) different from zero

Answer (score 0):

According to [Frozentux](https://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/chunkyhtml/x4529.html) "the *REDIRECT* target is used to redirect packets and streams to the machine itself [...] In other words, this rewrites the destination address to our own host for packets that are forwarded, or something alike."

You can try instead (command modified from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242772/using-iptables-to-change-a-destination-port):

`iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination <proxy_ip>:8080`

Comment: Okey ı will try and write you, much thx